# Can a rating control be used for Microsoft Store ratings?

Tags: c#, uwp

We are considering implementing a mechanism to ask users if they would like to give a Microsoft Store rating for our UWP application.

According to Microsoft's documentation, there are two ways to do so. Either by linking from the app into the Microsoft store, or by utilizing the RequestRateAndReviewAppAsync method from the store service. The latter method summons a native modal while in-app and would be our preferred means to request the user rate our app:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/request-ratings-and-reviews#show-a-rating-and-review-dialog-in-your-app

However, this mechanism seems a bit limited. Ideally, we would like to customize the user experience. i.e... add our own text and styling or even create a custom modal. Is there a way to do that with this native UI or somehow duplicate its functionality with something custom?

Delving a little deeper, I found out that Microsoft does provide a ratings control for UWP apps and it seems configurable. However, it is not clear to me if this component can be used for Microsoft Store app ratings. The examples I have browsed all show it being used for things like movie title ratings and other various little things.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/rating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a rating control be used for Microsoft Store ratings?

Unfortunately, currently there is no such restful api could submit the rating with custom UI, and store only provide two ways to submit the rating, one is link to store, other is show a rating and review dialog in your app as the document [mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/request-ratings-and-reviews#show-a-rating-and-review-dialog-in-your-app). If you do want this feature, please feel free post your requirement with Windows Feed Back Hub app.